# segmentation fault error when reading a file in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I was trying to read a file char by char but the debugger when reaches the fscanf gives back a segmentation fault error, here's my code:

```
int main(){
FILE *inFile;
char *carattere = NULL;

inFile = fopen("../file.txt", "r");
if (inFile == NULL){    
    return -1;
}

while(fscanf(inFile, "%c", carattere) != EOF){  //segmentation fault
    printf("%c ", *carattere);
}
fclose(inFile);
return 0;}
```

(I've recentely reinstalled my IDE).

Comment: Think about the space that `carattere` points to...

Comment: Suppose you wrote `fscanf(inFile, "%c", NULL)`.  What behavior would you expect?

Comment: You guys are right, basically I used a pointer whitout the referred thing, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide some space for your character to be read.
Where does `carattere` point to when you try to write into it?

Answer (score 1):

`carattere` is `NULL`, which cannot store even a single character. So, you need to give it some memory at least 2 bytes, 1<sup>st</sup> byte for the character itself and 2<sup>nd</sup> byte for `'\0'`.

So, initialize `carattere` like this:

```
char carattere[2] = { 0 };
```